# Loop Function in JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to make a recursive function in a jquery plugin that was made to change the image src attribute (and thus change the image...) again and again with set intervals in between. Now, when I log the data onto my console, the value of `x` is increasing as needed, but my images aren't changing.

So what I did was I logged `$(this).attr("id")` to cross check. Now the first time my function ran, my element's id was logging correctly but the second time, it was coming `undefined`. So something's wrong.

I need help in solving this problem and basically make the image change repeatedly.

Here is my plugin code:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.addimate = function(noOfImages, prefix, x, extension, interval) {

    if (x > noOfImages) {
        x = 1;
    }

    console.log($(this).attr("id") + "\n" + prefix + x + extension + "\n" + interval);
    $(this).attr("src", prefix + x + extension);
    x ++;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).addimate(noOfImages, prefix, x, extension, interval);
    }, interval);
}

}) (jQuery);
```

Help is HIGHLY appreciated. Thanks...

Comment: `this` is already an object in jQuery plugin so using `this` would get jQuery object instead of using $(this)

Comment: Can you represent it in code? Show it as an answer

Comment: I have added a code sample below. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing a jQuery plugin, you should understand that you're working with the jQuery object in the anonymous function because you're passing in jQuery to the function. So, when working with the jQuery instance, you don't need to use $(this) to work with the object. What you're doing when you use $(this) when in the jQuery namespace, is you're attempting to create a jQuery object of the jQuery object. That being said, this is not desirable, nor valid.

Take your code, for example:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.addimate = function(noOfImages, prefix, x, extension, interval) {

    //Intentionally deleted content.
}; //AND you're missing a semicolon here

}) (jQuery);
```

When someone calls $('.selector').addimate(), they're passing in $(.selector) to you're function. So, you're already working with a jQuery object. You're code should look like this.

```
(function($) {

$.fn.addimate = function(noOfImages, prefix, x, extension, interval) {

    var $this = this; //This will maintain the context of the jQuery object.

    if (x > noOfImages) {
        x = 1;
    }

    console.log(this.attr("id") + "\n" + prefix + x + extension + "\n" + interval);
    this.attr("src", prefix + x + extension);
    x++;

    setTimeout(function() {
        $this.addimate(noOfImages, prefix, x, extension, interval);
    }, interval);
};

}(jQuery));
```

Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2X4E/

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank You so much! I will keep in mind your advice about `$this` and `this`. Just one question: First you did `this.attr()` and then you did `$this.addimate()` in timeout. Can you tell me why you used `this` first and then `$this`. Why not just use `this` in both places?

Comment: So, the answer lies within the concept of the this pointer in JavaScript. this can be a hard concept to grasp. Just understand that this is referring whatever is calling the function. In this case, the object calling setTimeout is not jQuery, but the window. Try replacing  $this.addimate(...) with console.log(this) and see what happens.

Comment: well `this` shows top: window, location: Object etc. etc. and `$this` shows my selector and id... I see thank you...